# Freezing variables in Ruby doesn't work

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables

I am learning Ruby, and I just found interesting behaviour when using the `Object#freeze` method with variables.

After I freeze a variable (either `Fixnum` or `Array`), I am still able to modify it! It is strange, since as far as I am concerned this should not happen and `TypeError` should be raised.

Here's my code:

```
test = 666
var = 90
#ok
var += 5

puts "var.frozen? #{var.frozen?}"    
var.freeze    
puts "var.frozen? #{var.frozen?}"

var = test
puts "var = #{var}"
```

The same is for array:

```
test = [666]
var = [90]
#ok
var += [5]

puts "var.frozen? #{var.frozen?}"    
var.freeze    
puts "var.frozen? #{var.frozen?}"

var = test
puts "var = #{var}"
```

But when I try to push something into the array after freezing, it raises an arror, as expected:

```
test = [666]
var = [90]
#ok
var += [5]

puts "var.frozen? #{var.frozen?}"    
var.freeze    
puts "var.frozen? #{var.frozen?}"

var << test
puts "var = #{var}"
```

Can somebody explain to me this issue? It seems strange.

**Edit** I am using Windows XP + Ruby 1.9.3-p429

Comment: curious - why does `test` = `666` :P

Comment: That isn't what freezing does; it's working exactly as intended. You can't freeze immutable values like literal numbers, and you definitely can't "freeze" variables so they can't be set to new values. You only freeze objects.

Comment: @meagar: You can freeze immutables. It is just pointless because they cannot be changed anyway. But `5.freeze` does work ... in the sense that `5.frozen?`returns `true`.

Comment: @undur_gongor True, it's important that immutable values support the `freeze`/`frozen?` interface.

Comment: @sircapsalot: well, you do evil things with thise freeze method :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You freeze objects, not variables, i.e. you can't update a frozen object but you can assign a new object to the same variable. Consider this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.freeze
a << 4
# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array

# `b` and `a` references the same frozen object
b = a
b << 4    
# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array

# You can replace the object referenced by `a` with an unfrozen one
a = [4, 5, 6]
a << 7
# => [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

As an aside: it is quite useless to freeze `Fixnum`s, since they are immutable objects.

Comment: Well, is me being sloppy by referring to 'freezing variables', what I had in mind was of course freezing objects (variable is just a label in code so it makes no nense to 'freeze' it :))

Ok, i now understand how does this freezing work, but still, I am still a little bit confused, why assigning new object does not raise any. Is this somehow connected to 'aliasing', like eg:

#we have 1 object in memory and 1 aliases to it
obj1 = Object.new
obj1.freeze
obj1 = Object.new #obj1 now points to another object, but memory for first object is still "frozen" ?

Am I getting it right?

Comment: @FilipZymek You got it. :)

Comment: Ok, this make perfect sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

In Ruby, variables are references to objects. You freeze the object, not the variable.

Please note also that

```
a = [1, 2]
a.freeze
a += [3]
```

is not an error because `+` for arrays creates a new object.

Comment: Same for strings. +1 for the answer.
```ruby
a = 'test'.freeze # => "test"
a.frozen? # => true
a << '1' # RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
a += '1' # => "test1"
```

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in the other two answers, you freeze objects rather than variables.

I'd like to add a note on child objects, which aren't frozen when the parent is frozen. This can bite you hard if you don't pay attention to what you're doing, when exposing an object's internal structures:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :var
end

a = A.new
a.var = []
a.freeze
a.var = []   # this fails as expected
a.var << :a  # this works, raises no errors, and no warnings
```

You can read about the rational here:

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6037

Comment: this is usefull hint thanks!